# Firefox renders some characters smaller than the font size

Tags: html, firefox, unicode, fonts

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/75th/WSkHL/) with some Unicode characters.

```
<p>★★★½☆</p>
```

Here it is rendered in Safari, looking as expected:

[image: In Safari, the filled and open star characters are of a size with surrounding text]

Here it is in Firefox:

[image: In Firefox, they are considerably smaller than the surrounding text.]

I badly need Firefox to look like Safari. What exactly is going on here, and is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: What fonts are being used? I think that would be the main factor. The font used shouldn't "change size" without guidance - unless the glyphs are defined to be rendered so.

Comment: Doesn't seem to matter what font. The above is Times New Roman. The actual site I'm working on is using a Typekit font. Both exhibit this problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those characters aren't present in the font you're setting in your stylesheet, so the browser does fallback to some font that *does* have the characters.  This fallback is done on a character-by-character basis, so different fonts can ed up being used for different characters.  Specifically, I strongly doubt Times New Roman has those star characters.

I suggest setting a font that actually has the characters you're using in your stylesheet.

Comment: That does not appear to be the case. Arial contains this character but the result is the same. Half size in Firefox compared to Chrome. http://jsfiddle.net/WSkHL/1/

Comment: Interesting.  While Arial claims to contain U+2605, neither Firefox nor Chrome use that glyph from that font for me: changing the font-family from Arial to something else does not change the glyph being used, in either browser.

Comment: After extensive googling and some voodoo magic I was able to "fix" this by adding the "Arial Unicode MS" font to the CSS. It appears this font comes with MS Office. Haven't been able to try on a machine without office to see if the problem persists though. http://jsfiddle.net/WSkHL/2/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with © (copyright character) and I just wrapped it around a [span](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span) tag and then changed the font-family and font-size attribute as suggested in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17646658/3744182) by [Boris Zbarsky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/720912/boris-zbarsky), and it worked perfectly.