# In Firefox a special character used with the css content property is way thinner than in e.g. Safari/Chrome

Tags: css

Hi somehow i don't understand the differing display behaviour of a special character used within the content property in Firefox. i've stripped down everything and created a pen:

http://codepen.io/rpkoller/pen/Fbgav

In its' basic form the three lines are way thinner than e.g. within Safari or Chrome. If i add font-weight: bold they get a little bit thicker but still thinner than within Safari/Chrome. What is causing that significant difference in thickness and size (it seems the glyph itself is also displayed bigger in Firefox) towards the other browsers? Any hint would be appreciated. Thanks Ralf

Comment: Have you tried defining a font-family in that CSS for the after element? Maybe font-families aren't inherited to after/before elements. If then browsers have their own standard font-family, that might cause trouble. EDIT: both in Chrome and FireFox it looks the same to me.

Comment: I've tried to set the font-family in the parent as well as in the pseudo element. I've tried Signika, the font i use in the project i stumbled upon the issue, as well as Monospace (the only font which gave little bit better results). Aside the font-family i've tried altering font-weight and font-style. Still basically a significant difference in Firefox after all. :/

Comment: hmmm that is odd. It seems it might be a render(???) issue with certain fonts. if you set the font-family in the parent of the pseudo element it works with certain fonts. Arial and Courier are identical for example in all browsers. Helvetica and Signika differ like described above. :/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Firefox renders some characters smaller than the font size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643721/firefox-renders-some-characters-smaller-than-the-font-size)

Comment: interesting read. i've checked the signika webfont over at google and it really seems it is missing the specific glyph (… and i thought i had checked it before i've chosen that one). so it means that safari and chrome have the same fallback font (cuz of webkit) and firefox a different one. if i would have checked it in ie (i don't have one at  hand right now) i would get a third fallback version probably? but it totally makes sense now. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've noticed this too with other glyphs in the past; on certain glyphs the browsers just don't render the same! Have a look [at this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643721/firefox-renders-some-characters-smaller-than-the-font-size) for another example. I'd suggest for this problem that you should use either an icon font ([you can use a generator like IcoMoon](http://icomoon.io)), or alternately an SVG file.

Comment: Already commented on DanMans post which also applies to this one too. I guess i will either go with the icon font or a svg file cuz load a whole webfont just for one glyph would be a bit of an overkill. ;) Thanks to you two for helping me understand that issue!